# Reducer is not saving data to state in React Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing authentication functionality in my app and when I try to save auth token which I get from my backend to reducer state it does nothing... I am new to this so there may be some dumb error.

This is my `store.js` file:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const initialState = { access_token: null };

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_TOKEN":
            console.log(action.data) // this does return the token which means data is passed correctly
            return { access_token: action.data };
        case "REMOVE_TOKEN":
            return { access_token: null };
        default:
            return initialState;
    }
};

export const Context = React.createContext();
```

This is my root component file `AppRouter.js`:

```js
function AppRouter() {
    const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const access_token = store.access_token;
    console.log(access_token);
    const AuthenticatedRoute = GuardedRoute(access_token);
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{store, dispatch}}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen}/>
                    <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterScreen}/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginScreen}/>
                    <AuthenticatedRoute component={DashboardScreen} exact path={"/dashboard"}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

So to me all this looks fine, and then this is the `_login` function in which I send the `dispatch()` to save the token(EDIT: this is everything between start of component function and `return()`:

```js
  const [afterSuccessRegister, setAfterSuccessRegister] = useState(false);
  const [emailInput, setEmailInput] = useState("");
  const [passwordInput, setPasswordInput] = useState("");
  const [loginErrorMessage, setLoginErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [createdUserEmail, setCreatedUserEmail] = useState("");

  const { store, dispatch } = useContext(Context);

  const _login = () => {
    axios.post(`${ROOT_API}/v1/users/login`, {
      "user": {
        "email": emailInput,
        "password": passwordInput
      }
    }, {}).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      dispatch({type: 'SET_TOKEN', data: res.data.meta.access_token});
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response);
      setLoginErrorMessage(err.response.data.message)
    })
  };

  const _handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmailInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const _handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPasswordInput(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof props.location.state !== "undefined") {
      if (typeof props.location.state.success_register === 'undefined' || props.location.state.success_register === null || props.location.state.success_register === false) {
        console.log("login");
      } else {
        setAfterSuccessRegister(true);
        setCreatedUserEmail(props.location.state.created_user_email);
        delete props.location.state;
      }
    }
  }, [props.location.state]);
```

I really don't know why is it not saving it even though data is passed correctly. I tried adding `console.log(store.access_token)` after my login request has finished to see if it was saved, but it returns `null`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have u tried redux-persist?

Comment: I am not looking to get into redux at this moment, I would like to keep it simple with context

Comment: Are you retrieving `dispatch` from the context on `login`?

Comment: You mean like this `  const { store, dispatch } = useContext(Context);`?

Comment: @crodev yes, is that how you are retrieving`dispatch`?

Comment: Yes, it is right above the function

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No, the value is just null. It doesnt save it.

Comment: Can you share more of your login component code that we can see  _login outer scope?

Comment: I can but I wouldn't say the problem is in the login component. Because I did a `console.log("here")` in the `case "SET_TOKEN"` and when `_login()` is run, it does log the message so it means that "SET_TOKEN" case is being run. And it logs out `action.data` so I know it recieves data. But anyways I'll provide some more code.